# Spring Boot Config File - Can JSON object go in?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web, redis

In my Spring boot application, I need to store the list of State and some configuration related to State. For example - State of GA and FL allows lottery, but Hawaai do not.. so my JSON object that store this info looks like

```
states:[
 {"code":"GA", "lottery":"yes"},
 {"code":"HI", "lottery":"no"}
..
}
```

Bear with me..if this sounds like naive question. I am trying to find out if application.properties is a nice place to store this kind of information. I mean, I can either store in the properties and load at startup..or move it to a Database and do the same. But since application.properties is handy and does not require connecting to a database, sounds like an easy approach. Need your views. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could keep that  as a separate json file on your classpath (The same location where your application.properties is) in Spring boot and later load it in your code.

Comment: It would be possible to pass in your JSON as String and later parse it to an object. But it feels kinda wrong. As the name suggests this file is meant for **properties**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The configuration is too complicated. New statelottery.json file
   {"GA": "yes", "HI": "no"}
2. Read the json file. Then json2map. I don't think there is any difficulty. It has nothing to do with springboot.